# Pass object from one controller action to another controller action in spring mvc3

Tags: spring

in my project i have one to many mapping between company and location.While adding location i want company object.
I have two differnt controller for company and location

In company Controller:
    addCompany

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addCompany(@ModelAttribute("company")
Company company, BindingResult result,Model model) {
    companyService.addCompany(company);
   return "companyPage";
  }
```

updateCompany

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateCompany(@ModelAttribute("company")
Company company, BindingResult result,@RequestParam(value = "submitVal") String updateOrRestore
,Model model) {

    if (updateOrRestore.equalsIgnoreCase("update")) {
            companyService.updateCompany(company);
            model.addAttribute("location", new Location());

        } else if (updateOrRestore.equalsIgnoreCase("restore")) {
            Company prevCompany = companyService.restoreCompany();
            model.addAttribute("company", prevCompany);
            model.addAttribute("location", new Location());
        }

      return "companyPage";
}
```

In location Controller:
addLocation

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addLocation", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public String addLocation(@ModelAttribute("location")
Location location,BindingResult reult, Model model){
    logger.info("Location is added"+location);
    //Here b4 adding location in db i want to set company obj
    //location.setCompany(company);
    locationService.addLocation(location);
}
```

How can i get company object that one is save or updated in company controller action??

Comment: use companyID as hidden in form and use that ID to get company object in location controller

Comment: @OomphFortuity  How to do that??Any example or reference

Comment: Give us exact flow of your View and controller with Get-Post-Redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get Company object from DB with help of Its ID.
You have to maintain this ID in hidden input box inside form post and do in controller like below

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addLocation", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public String addLocation(@ModelAttribute("location")
Location location,BindingResult reult, Model model,@requestParam("cmpID") long ID){
    //Company companyObj=get from DB with help of ID
    //location.setCompany(companyObj);
    locationService.addLocation(location);
    return "yourview";
}
```